# Please, add icons to famous tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

If you go to Stack Overflow and see the list of popular tags, you'll find icons on some tags like Android, Angular etc. We'll also like such icons.

Star Trek can have its icon because [it has one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek#/media/File:Emblem.svg). Marvel, Vader etc. can also have icons.

Please, add icons to some famous tags. Or, allow us to do that as a part of tag wiki.

Comment: Great idea. Won't happen, but great idea.

Comment: @Valorum Convince Disney to pony up some cold hard cash and I bet it would happen quickly.

Comment: @Skooba Or, maybe, we can crowdfund couple of tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These tags don't have icons "just because"; they are sponsored tags. See this [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/30188/345161), for example.

> This is a sponsored tag - in other words, a company has decided to pay money to put an icon and to put links on the tag page. Moderators cannot edit these; they are only added as a result of a tag sponsorship.
>
> The tag sponsorship program is currently active on Stack Overflow only.

You're welcome to sponsor some tags to get the icons yourself. However, as the icon is provided by the sponsor I'm not sure if you would be able to use an official logo like you propose here without running into legal issues.

Comment: The tag icons are also there on Server Fault. Try `google-cloud-platform` tag..

Comment: It also wouldn't apply to SF&F, since AFAIK they aren't supporting sponsored tags right now on this site.

Comment: @JMac To be honest I have no idea, the above mentions SFF only but obviously since then other sites have had them so I don't know how much support is available.

Comment: @JMac I believe Marvel can make that happen. All you need is money. Features can be implemented anytime.

Comment: @Lobo I was more talking about SE's end.  They don't seem to be branching out to SF&F sponsored tags right now; it's only a feature on a couple sites which are much closer to SE's main source of network traffic.