# Could we allow sponsored tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, another debate is brewing on the usefulness of non-Stack Overflow sites to the company, specifically bringing up profitability.

Could this site allow [tag sponsorships](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) a la Stack Overflow? SF&F seems an ideal stomping ground for sponsorships - Disney could have a ball sponsoring [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [frozen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frozen), WB could sponsor [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc), [superman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superman), and [batman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman), and Nintendo could sponsor [pokemon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon). There are dozens of tags directly relevant to some publisher or studio, and sponsorships could be relatively in-obtrusive (compared to banner ads) or even fun, and that could help the site bring in a little more money to justify its existence.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12686/58193)

Comment: I don't think there'd be many qualms over adding them from us users, you've got to convince SE and the companies instead.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot right. The answer to that question is that it's not currently possible to have tag icons because the site does not offer tag sponsorships. This is a feature request to change that and start offering sponsorships. The company has some advertising gurus that I'm sure could make a decent pitch to a few companies.

Comment: Aye I'm aware, I linked it because it was still somewhat fresh in my mind and it is related not because I was considering closing it as a duplicate.

Comment: What'd be the point of 90% of tags having the Disney logo, though?

Comment: Why would these companies *want* to sponsor tags here? What would they get out of it? I'm not sure what the business case is for tag sponsorship on SO, but does it apply here on SciFi?